# Function returns unexpected pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-address

I'm working on a simple C program with nested structures and unions, and I got a problem returning a pointer to a char array.

Here is the code :

```
#define BUFSIZE 32

typedef enum {
  S1 = 0,
  S2
} type_t;

typedef struct {
  int x, y;
  char value[BUFSIZE];
} s1_t;

typedef struct {
  s1_t s;
  char value2[BUFSIZE];
} s2_t;

typedef struct {
  type_t t;
  union {
    s1_t s1;
    s2_t s2;
  };
} s3_t;

s3_t* new_s1(int x, int y, char* value) {
  s3_t* s;
  if ((s = malloc(sizeof(s3_t))) == NULL)
    return NULL;
  memset(s, 0, sizeof(s3_t));
  s->t = S1;
  s->s1.x = x;
  s->s1.y = y;
  strncpy(s->s1.value, value, BUFSIZE);
  return s;
}

s3_t* new_s2(int x, int y, char* value, char* value2) {
  s3_t* s;
  if ((s = malloc(sizeof(s3_t))) == NULL)
    return NULL;
  memset(s, 0, sizeof(s3_t));
  s->t = S2;
  s->s2.s.x = x;
  s->s2.s.y = y;
  strncpy(s->s2.s.value, value, BUFSIZE);
  strncpy(s->s2.value2, value2, BUFSIZE);
  return s;
}

// The problem comes from this function ?
char* get_value(s3_t s) {
  return (s.t == S1) ? s.s1.value : s.s2.s.value;
}

int main(void) {
  s3_t *a, *b;
  char *p1, *p2;
  if ((a = new_s1(1, 2, "A")) == NULL)
    return 1;
  if ((b = new_s2(1, 2, "ABCD", "VAL2")) == NULL)
    return 2;
  p1 = get_value(*a);
  printf("a (%p) => P1 : (%p - %s) - (%p - %s)\n", a, p1, p1, a->s1.value, a->s1.value);
  p2 = get_value(*b);
  printf("b (%p) => P1 : (%p - %s) - (%p - %s)\n", b, p2, p2, b->s2.s.value, b->s2.s.value);
  printf("strcmp(p1,p2) = %d\n", strcmp(p1, p2));
  free(a);
  free(b);
  return 0;
}
```

And the output :

```
a (0x1974010) => P1 : (0x7fff085df16c - A) - (0x197401c - A)
b (0x1974070) => P2 : (0x7fff085df16c - ABCD) - (0x197407c - ABCD)
strcmp(p1,p2) = 0
```

The problem is that the pointers returned by the `get_value` function are the same, even if the params are not ("a", then "b"), so `strcmp()` returns 0.
As you see, `get_value(*a)` returns the pointer `0x7fff085df16c`, why not `0x197401c` ?

Because the pointers returned are the same, if I change the main in :

```
// ...
p1 = get_value(*a);
p2 = get_value(*b);
printf("a (%p) => P1 : (%p - %s) - (%p - %s)\n", a, p1, p1, a->s1.value, a->s1.value);
printf("b (%p) => P2 : (%p - %s) - (%p - %s)\n", b, p2, p2, b->s2.s.value, b->s2.s.value);
printf("strcmp(p1,p2) = %d\n", strcmp(p1, p2));
// ...
```

The string value of p1 is overwritten by the string value of p2.
So the output looks like :

```
a (0x1156010) => P1 : (0x7fffb81d8cbc - ABCD) - (0x115601c - A)
b (0x1156070) => P2 : (0x7fffb81d8cbc - ABCD) - (0x115607c - ABCD)
strcmp(p1,p2) = 0
```

Of course, I can fix this by changing the function `get_value` to make it copy the string and return another pointer.

```
char* get_value(s3_t s) {
  char* p;
  if ((p = malloc(BUFSIZE)) == NULL)
    return NULL;
  strncpy(p, ((s.t == S1) ? s.s1.value : s.s2.s.value), BUFSIZE);
  return p;
}
```

But I don't (and I want to) understand why the pointer returned by `get_value` is different from the pointer in the structure. Did I miss something ?

Comment: There is no "pointer in the structure". Your structure only contains ints and arrays. Arrays and pointers are different things.  The array in `get_value`'s copy of `s` is in a different memory location to the array in the original struct that was copied from.

Comment: Also: unrelated to your main issue, but the `strncpy` function sometimes does not null-terminate the buffer. If your intent is to treat the buffer as containing a string, you'll need to do something else (e.g. manually terminate it, or my preference, `snprintf`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure/Union types (all types, really) in C are passed by-value.

So in this code:

```
char* get_value(s3_t s) {

}
```

the compiler will allocate an `s3_t` on the stack and the caller will copy its contents into the stack space allocated.

By returning the contents of `s.s1.value`, you're returning a pointer to space that was allocated on the stack.  This memory gets deallocated when `get_value()` returns to the 
caller.

Some compilers are kind enough to warn you when you make this error.  For example, I took your `get_value()` to `clang` with `-Wall` and got the following:

```
$ /opt/llvm+clang-3.4/bin/clang -Wall  -o pbv.o -c pbv.c 
pbv.c:28:24: warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 's' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
  return (s.t == S1) ? s.s1.value : s.s2.s.value;
                       ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: @OP, the simplest way to fix this would be `char *get_value(s3_t *s)`

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot this detail... I'm compiling with gcc 4.8.1 with -Wall and -Wextra flags, but there is no such warning.

Comment: Yeah, I thought `gcc` would catch it too.

Answer (score 1):

This function you called:

```
char* get_value(s3_t s) {
  return (s.t == S1) ? s.s1.value : s.s2.s.value;
}
```

This function takes value as the parameter (not a pointer).. 
You should make something like:

```
char* get_value(s3_t *s) {
  return (s->t == S1) ? s->s1.value : s->s2.s.value;
}
```

and

```
p1 = get_value(a);
```

That if you want to preserve the pointer from the caller..